# How to add NSMutableArray as objectAtIndex for NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How to add `NSMutableArray` as an object(i) for another `NSMutableArray`

My code is:

```
yearImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i =0; i< [yearImagesName count]; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<[totalImagesName count]; j++)
    {
        if ([[totalImagesName objectAtIndex:j] rangeOfString:[yearImagesName objectAtIndex:i]].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [tempImages addObject:[totalImagesName objectAtIndex:j]];
        }

    }

    [yearImages addObject:tempImages]; 
    [tempImages removeAllObjects];
}

NSLog(@"\n\n  year%@",[yearImages objectAtIndex:0]); // getting null result
```

- Here i need to add tempImages as object of (i) for yearImages..
- I need result as like follows:

---

```
[yearImages objectAtIndex:i];// result need as arrayobjects here
```

Comment: what error r u getting? Post the actual compiler error...

Comment: try to change [yearImages insertObject:tempImages atIndex:i]; to [yearImages addObject:tempImages];

Comment: @Chancy: These both will be same..

Comment: @Chancy: am changed but still getting result null

Comment: `null` plz check have you initialised every object in your code?

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya: am initialized all but null only am getting

Comment: thanks for everyone who all gave suggestions to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the objects from tempImages after you add it, so the result will be an array of empty arrays. You should add a copy of tempImages instead:
`[yearImages addObject:tempImages.copy]`
(or a mutableCopy if you require that)

Answer (score 1):

Does this even compile? `k` in `[yearImages insertObject:tempImages atIndex:k]` is not declared at all.

What error are you getting?

In order to simplify your code, you could get rid of the indices using this code.

```
yearImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSString *yearImageName in yearImagesName)
{
    for(NSString *totalImageName in totalImagesName)
    {
        if ([totalImageName rangeOfString:yearImageName].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [tempImages addObject:totalImageName];
        }
    }

    [yearImages addObject:tempImages];
    [tempImages removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: i need to add temp1 array as[yearImages objectAtIndex:0], temp2 array as[yearImages objectAtIndex:1],

Comment: there is no error in if loop.. i got temp array separately each time. but i need whole temp data in yearimage array

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple.

Replace `[yearImages objectAtIndex:i]` into `[yearImages addObject:tempImages.copy]`

Now see full code:

```
for(int i =0; i< [yearImagesName count]; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<[totalImagesName count]; j++)
    {
        if (// Your Conditon)
        {
            [tempImages addObject:[totalImagesName objectAtIndex:j]];
        }

    }

    [yearImages addObject:tempImages.copy]; // each array stored as an object
    [tempImages removeAllObjects];
}
NSLog(@"\n\n  year%@",[yearImages objectAtIndex:0]);
```