# Order two NSMutablearray into one NSMutableArray by closest match to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have two `NSMutableArray` objects, and I would like to have one `NSMutableArray` instance that is ordered by closest match to a `NSString`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "ordered by closest match to a NSString"?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you explain what are the element types?

Comment: The initial two NSMutableArrays are NSStrings. I want to order them by closest match to a given NSString.  Example: 
array 1 {Math101,math,ma}
array 2 {Math10,time,fun}
Key = Math101
final array={math101,math10,math,ma,fun,time}

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Try this link. Am already got solution for this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262727/how-to-add-nsmutablearray-as-objectatindex-for-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an [NSComparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) and use something like the [Levenshtein distance from string1](https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField/blob/master/MLPAutoCompleteTextField/NSString%2BLevenshtein.h) as the function for your comparison. If you need a code example. leave a comment and I'll edit this response to include one.